# Issues trying to get Index Location in IList

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

```
class IList2
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Locations test = new Locations();
        Location loc = new Location();
        string sSite = "test";
        test.Add(sSite);
        string site = loc.Site; 
        Location finding = test.Where(i => i.Site == site).FirstOrDefault();
        int index = finding == null ? -1 : test.IndexOf(finding); 
    }
}

public class Location
{
    public Location()
    {

    }
    private string _site = string.Empty;
    public string Site
    {
        get { return _site; }
        set { _site = value; }
    }
 }

 public class Locations : IList<Location>
 {
    List<Location> _locs = new List<Location>();

    public Locations() { }

    public int IndexOf(Location item)
    {

        return _locs.IndexOf(item);

    }
    //then the rest of the interface members implemented here in IList
    public void Add(string sSite)
    {
        Location loc = new Location();
        loc.Site = sSite;

        _locs.Add(loc);
    }
  }

  IEnumerator<Location> IEnumerable<Location>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _locs.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

I got helped a bit in this post: [Trying to call int IList<Location>.IndexOf(Location item) method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793908/trying-to-call-int-ilistlocation-indexoflocation-item-method)

I tried to get this working but I always seem to get -1 as the index number. I know string `site = loc.Site;` is empty after realizing that so I don't know exactly how to get the index from the IList at this point.

To clear up what I'm trying to accomplish, I want to learn how to use the IList interface members and I started out with the IndexOf interface.

The IList is populated with more than just "sSite" but I just reduce the list to just "sSite" for an example purpose.

So in the middle of learning, I hit this bump in the road and been staring at the code for a few days (yes I take breaks and look at other stuff as not to tire myself out).

So the main issue is that I keep getting index = -1.

Comment: SO which index you are expecting given empty list?!

Comment: This is really confusing what you're trying to do. On line 3 of the Main function, what is loc? I don't see it declared anywhere in that method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not clear on what your intention is here but in the code snippet "loc" is never used because you create a new `Location` in the "Add" method and "site" is (as you've noted) always empty but in the "Add" method you pass in a value and set it on the newly created instance so unless you passed string.Empty as a value the comparison `i.Site == site` will always be `false`. If you remove those and rewrite as:

```
Locations test = new Locations();
string sSite = "test";
test.Add(sSite);
Location finding = test.Where(i => i.Site == sSite).FirstOrDefault();
int index = test.IndexOf(finding);
```

Then this returns `0` as the index.

Comment: Opps thanks for catching that mistake. Ok I did what you suggested before and for some reason I didn't catch on. Thanks I really appreciate. Just one more question. If I added a 2nd value in test.Add(sSite, sBldg) call sBldg, is there a way to find the location of that value using indexOf?

Comment: You can add sBldg to your query, as in `test.Where(i => i.Site == sSite && i.Building == sBldg).FirstOrDefault()`, assuming that you have a property "Building" which is initialized in your `Add(sSite,sBldg)` method in the same way as "Site".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have this in the beginning:

```
Location loc = new Location();
loc.Site = "test";
```

You will get your index.

Also it is bit confusing, because very unclear what you want to accomplish here.
Note that this line of code:

```
test.Where(i => i.Site == site).FirstOrDefault();
```

will return you value only if following is true: "i.Site == site", of course which cannot happen if you provide something not existing in list.